# URL(string:) Cannot call value of non-function type 'String'

Tags: swift, url, swift3, nsurl

I have the follow code but I am getting an error.

```
if let userImageURL = user.image {
    let url = URL(string: userImageURL)
}
```

How am I supposed to create url? `URL(string:)` is supposed to take a `String` isn't it? And that's what `userImageURL` is.

EDIT: Here's an example of the code I'm trying to implement. Even in this example, I'm getting the same error for `catPictureURL`

```
let catPictureURL = URL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/w5rkSIj.jpg")!

// Creating a session object with the default configuration.
// You can read more about it here https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration
let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)

// Define a download task. The download task will download the contents of the URL as a Data object and then you can do what you wish with that data.
let downloadPicTask = session.dataTask(with: catPictureURL) { (data, response, error) in
    // The download has finished.
    if let e = error {
        print("Error downloading cat picture: \(e)")
    } else {
        // No errors found.
        // It would be weird if we didn't have a response, so check for that too.
        if let res = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            print("Downloaded cat picture with response code \(res.statusCode)")
            if let imageData = data {
                // Finally convert that Data into an image and do what you wish with it.
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                // Do something with your image.
            } else {
                print("Couldn't get image: Image is nil")
            }
        } else {
            print("Couldn't get response code for some reason")
        }
    }
}

downloadPicTask.resume()
```

Comment: That code should compile (assuming that `user.image` has type `String?`). Please show a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I've updated my post

Comment: Again: That code *does compile.*

Answer (score 25):

You need to make object of URL like this

```
let url = Foundation.URL(string:"your_url_string")
```

Answer (score 7):

In my case this was a namespace problem.

The variable named `URL` was mucking with the standard `URL` Type.

Use `Foundation.URL` in your code or rename the `URL` variable.

```
struct NamespaceTest {

    let exampleURL = "http://example.com/"

    var URL: URL {

        // ERROR: Cannot call value of non-function type 'URL'
        return URL(string: exampleURL)!

        // OK
        return Foundation.URL(string: exampleURL)!
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Was having the same problem, still couldn't figure it out all the way.
Feels like an Xcode 8 bug, because according to apple's website it should work (reference: [Apple's URL reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url))

anyways, I used a workaround for this:

```
let imageUrl = NSURL(string: "www.apple.com") as! URL
```

Comment: worked for me smoothly, I don't know what is the problem with this that it hasn't fixed yet, I used the exact line of code two lines below and it works like hell but this one give me this stupid error log!